# Rotating a CSS3 3d cube with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying  to rotate a 3d cube with two controls - for left and right. When you click on the left button, for example, I'd like to add extra 40 degrees to the rotateY value on the left.

My question is: Since I can't work with exact values (I want everytime to add new values to the existing ones!), I guess I will have to split up the string for the transform into something like this:

```
$(cube).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(-100deg) rotateZ(-50deg + add 40 degrees to the existing one!) translateZ(-30px)");
```

Here is the pen I am working on:

http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/hHEBG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to keep track of the rotation is to do it yourself, as jQuery's `css()` will return the matrix, and then you'll have to calculate that etc. and it's just easier to keep track of the value in an attribute instead.

Keep the value in a data attribute, and increment that together with the css value, and it should be straight forward, and it's accessible from other functions as well.

```
cube.data('rot', -50);

left.click(function(){
  var deg = cube.data('rot') + 40;

  cube.css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(-100deg) rotateZ("+deg+"deg) translateZ(-30px)");

  cube.data('rot', deg);
});

right.click(function(){
  var deg = cube.data('rot') - 40;

  cube.css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(-100deg) rotateZ("+deg+"deg) translateZ(-30px)");

  cube.data('rot', deg);
});
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EibhI)

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of the rotation and increment it on each click with JS, this is what you can do :

*jQuery :*

```
var btn = $('.nav'),
    body = $('body'),
    cube = $(".cube"),
    left = $('.left'),
    v_transZ = -40 ;

// REST OF YOUR jQuery CODE

left.click(function(){
  v_transZ = v_transZ - 10;
  var counter = 0,
      v_trans = 'rotateX(-100deg) rotateZ('+ v_transZ +'deg) translateZ(-30px)';

  $(cube).css("-webkit-transform", v_trans);

});
```

As you are using CSS3 transitions, I would tend to use them also to rotate the cube and use JS only to trigger the animation with class changes on click. But as you ask for a JS solution...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are changing the angle on only one axis this is not exactly what you are looking for, but it might give you a clue:
[Css Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/)

I would try to solve the problem completely in the meantime, though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your question is about how to keep do incremental changes (instead of hardcoded ones) or how to find a more elegant way for setting those values.

For the first one, I think the only way is to keep track of rotation values in your JavaScript code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dsIgn (I worked on it in Firefox, just change back `-moz-` to `-webkit-`.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a variable outside the click function and store the current value there

Then in every click you add 40 to that variable

JS

```
var currentRotateZ = -50

left.click(function(){
    $(cube).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(-100deg) rotateZ(" + (currentRotateZ += 40) + "deg) translateZ(-30px)");
});
```